# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent" when restarting my application?

Tags: android

I have extended my `Application` class and start some background services there. This is my `Application` class:

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startService(Intent(this, SocketService::class.java))
        startService(Intent(this, MonitoringService::class.java))
}
```

Everything goes well when I start my application for the first time. However, if I destroy all my activities when swipping up on them and then try to start my application again, I get the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.domain/.socket.SocketService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7623211 u0a133 SVC  idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}`

From my understanding, the `Application` class was the "longest-living component" and that if it was destroyed, then all my services would also have been destroyed. However, it seems that my services may still be running.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you start a service instead binding it , actually the service will continue to work after app is closed for some minutes

Comment: @Mr.AF Thanks for the reply! Is there a way I can kill all services when the application class dies? I can only find a `onLowMemory` method for the application class and it doesn't seem to be guaranteed to be called. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Yea you can , there are many ways doing that but binding service to your activity is the easiest approach . then after app is closed all bound services will be killed.

Comment: @Mr.AF Could I bind it to my `Application` class instead? I don't want activities to manage my lifecycle and need a guarantee that all my services will be started when the app is launched.

Comment: Application is run on a context and all bound services use this context . actually Application is not a independent part of your activity , it run on activity as well.

Comment: this keyword means this context or this activity

Comment: @Mr.AF Thanks, it works like a charm!